# jq print if its a dependency or devdependency with version number

Tags: json, bash, jq, package.json

Recently came across jq library, https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ which promises to solve a problem I'm facing. Given a package name, I want to be able to print if its devdependency or dependency and also print the line so that I get the version number.

**If I input "split":**

**Expected output:**

> dependencies, "split": "0.3.0".

### sample package.json

```
{
    "name": "universe",
    "devDependencies":
    {
        "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
        "lucene-query-parser": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies":
    {
        "async": "^0.2.10",
        "npm2es": "~0.4.2",
        "optimist": "~0.6.0",
        "request": "~2.30.0",
        "skateboard": "^1.5.1",
        "split": "0.3.0",
        "weld": "^0.2.2"
    }

}
```

With my limited experience with the jq library, I am able to get a true or false value for dependency/devDependency but I need to get the above expected output. Anything that gets me closer to the above expected output is fine too.

This is my query:

> jq -c '{dependencies: .dependencies, devDependencies: .devDependencies}' package.json |  jq .[] | jq 'contains({ "split"})'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one straightforward (if rather pedestrian) solution:

```
.devDependencies[$name] as $v
| if $v then "devDependencies, \"\($name)\": \"\($v)\""
  else .dependencies[$name] as $v
  | if $v then "dependencies, \"\($name)\": \"\($v)\"" else empty end
  end
```

### Invocation

```
jq --arg name split -r -f program.jq input.json
```

### More economically

```
{devDependencies,dependencies}
| map_values(.[$name])
| to_entries[]
| select(.value)
| "\(.key), \"\($name)\": \"\(.value)"
```

### More generically

```
(paths | select( .[-1] == $name )) as $p
| "\($p[-2]), \"\($name)\": \"\(getpath($p))\""
```

Comment: Removing the -nr made it work. The final query is >>> .                                                      jq --arg name gridfs-stream -f program.jq package.json

Comment: You'll probably want to keep the -r option.

Comment: awesome, I was wondering why I was getting \ all over the result and was stripping it out using sed. Now that is gone with -r. Thanks.